# what is capture mode on an event listener

Tags: vue.js

In the vue docs under [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), there's an example of a modifier called `capture` which states the following:

```
<!-- use capture mode when adding the event listener -->
<div v-on:click.capture="doThis">...</div>
```

I've done some searching, but haven't found a clear answer as to how this modifies the event binding, then I thought to myself 'You know who always has the answer?  Stack Overflow'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is event bubbling and capturing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: it's a Vue-specific question, the answer to which references bubbling & capturing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So right after posting I stumbled on [this article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing) which illustrates it clearly.  Let's say for this example that you have three elements nested within each other:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a click event occurs, there are two phases: the first is called **capturing**, the second is called **bubbling**.  When you click on the `.inner`, the event traverses down from the outermost container element `.outer`, to `.middle`, then to `.inner` in the **capturing** phase, then from `.inner` to `.middle`, then to `.outer` in the **bubbling** phase.

If **capture** is set on `.inner` for a click event handler:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner" v-on:click.capture="doThis"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you click on it, it will hit `.outer`, then `.middle`, then `.inner` in the capture phase, which will cause `doThis(...)` to be called, after which the bubbling phase begins.

If **capture** is set on `.middle` for a click event handler

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle" v-on:click.capture="doThis">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you click on it, it will hit `.outer`, then `.middle`, in the capture phase, which will cause `doThis(...)` to be called, then hit `.inner` in the capture phase, after which the bubbling phase begins.

Edit: Thanks for all the great responses below, I've amended the answer to fix where I was incorrect.

Comment: just to clarify, would the event actually be called (at least) 5 times, because it will be called on `<body>` and `<html>` tags too? Or does Vue consider capture mode to apply only within its instance's root element?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Each element's event handler will be triggered only once, the difference is when it's triggered (before it's child or after it's child). Capture mode triggers before the child. Bubble mode (the default), after the child.

You can even put a capture mode and bubble mode event handler like

<div v-on:click="doThis" v-on:click.capture="doThis">

Comment: This fiddle demonstrates how a single click to inner can trigger a maximum of 6 event handlers. https://jsfiddle.net/7uvh0fnz/1

Comment: I agree with  @absolutelyNoWarranty it is noting to do with number of execution of that event listener but when that even listener get executed compare to its predecessor's and ancestor's even listener

Comment: @absolutelyNoWarranty You should post your jsfiddle code that disproves this answer as a separate answer here.  It's a really helpful demo.

Answer (score 17):

Both bubble and capture event handlers on an element will be triggered **only once**, the difference is when they are triggered (*before* the children or *after* the children). Capture mode means the handler is triggered before any handlers on child elements. Bubble mode (the default), means the handler is triggered after all child elements have finished their handlers. You can even put a capture mode and bubble mode event handler by doing `<div v-on:click="doThis" v-on:click.capture="doThis">`

This [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uvh0fnz/1) demonstrates how a single click to a nested inner element first triggers capture handlers in an "outer-to-inner" order, and then triggers bubble handlers in an "inner-to-outer" order.